# Add locations to Google MyMaps layer via Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

My client has a map with a layer containing the locations of organizations associated with users registered to their site.  Is it possible to use a REST API or similar to create these locations transparently, to relieve the client from having to add these locations manually?

Answer (score 1):

I believe currently there is no any REST API for this.

The Place Add/Delete API was deprecated

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html

There is no any replacement for Place Add announced by Google.